# Nested gridview in repeater not exported in pdf

Tags: repeater

I'm trying to export several gridviews in pdf and they are not rendered in HtmlTextWriter
The gridviews are created dynamically, being nested in a repeater control.
As data source I'm using a datatable, and despite the tables are displayed in browser (together with their data), they are not rendered in pdf file.

Below the code
Thanks!

ASPX:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptResult" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptResult_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>                                
                Detalii test<br />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltGroupId12" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("GroupId12")%>'></asp:Literal>                    
                <asp:GridView ID="gvResultDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" GridLines="Both"
                     OnRowDataBound="gvResultDetail_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Group1Desc" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewItemGroup1TestResult" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Group2Desc" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewItemGroup2TestResult"/>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewItemStdTestResult">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                test
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRequestedResultText" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Position request<br />Total: "></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRequestedResultValue" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("RequestedResult")%>'></asp:Label>                                
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewItemStdTestResult">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblActualResultText" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Answer level<br />Total: "></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblActualResultValue" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ActualResult")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewItemStdTestResult">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDifferencesText" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Difference:"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDifferencesValue" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Differences")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="gridviewItemStdTestResult">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPercentageText" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="KQ<br />"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPercentageValue" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Percentage") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Literal ID="ltGroupType" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("RecordType")%>'></asp:Literal>
                                <asp:Literal ID="ltNoRows" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("NoRows")%>'></asp:Literal>
                                <asp:Literal ID="ltBasicDomain" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("BasicDomain")%>'></asp:Literal>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewHeaderTestResult" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="gridviewRowTestResult" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridviewRowTestResult" />                
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>                
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <br />
            </SeparatorTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                End
            </FooterTemplate>        
        </asp:Repeater>

        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
```

ASPX.CS:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SDT.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
DataTable dtDetailedResult = (DataTable)Session["dtDetailedResult"];
    rptResult.DataSource = dtDetailedResult;
    rptResult.DataBind();        
    pnlContent.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70f, 70f, 20f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about nested gridviews but for exporting gridview to pdf you have to download itextsharp.dll from internet and place it in bin folder of your project.

There's an example with sample output of how to export gridview to pdf. You can refer it here.

[export-gridview-to-pdf](http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.in/2010/01/export-gridview-to-pdf-in-aspnet-using.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is exactly I use, itextsharp.dll - but only already defined aspx tables/gridviews are "seen" by htmltextwriter and displayed in pdf file, those generated dynamically by using nested controls in repeater items are not rendered....

Comment: I have ended up in writing html tags embeded with my data from datatable source - if you have another solution please let me know, something like: hw.Write("<table border='2'>");
                    hw.Write("<tr>");
                    hw.Write("<td style='background-color:Red'>");
                    hw.Write(dtDetailedResult.Rows[i]["Group1Desc"].ToString());